# How to solve “unmet dependencies while installing CUDA-9-0 on Ubuntu 18.04”

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA-9-0 on Ubuntu 18.04, but I get the following error when I run the command `sudo apt install cuda`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have `nVidia-driver-390` properly installed installed. 
I try to install CUDA using .deb local file installation method as described on the website of nVidia [Here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1704&target_type=deblocal)

I use the .deb file for Ubuntu 17.04

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Show the repository which you try to use for this package installation.

Comment: There is no repo, as I stated in my question, I am using .deb local file installation method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by removing the nVidia driver and reinstalling it.
What I did is :

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

and then re-installed it using:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

I am using `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` for nVidia drivers. The repo is added using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

I don't know what was the reason, but as you see removing and re-installing solved the problem.